# how to edit View core file in custom module in opencart

Tags: opencart

i am developing a module in opencart 2.1.0.1, and need to modify core view file (order_info.tpl) that changes i am done by using rewriting that file in (system/storage) but i want that changes only when that module is active (when i will deactivae that module that modification should deactivae too)
how to do this ?

added these fildes

```
 <div style='display:none;' id='business' class="form-group">
                <div class="col-sm-2 text-right padding5"><label class="">Date</label></div>
                <div class='col-sm-4'>                               
                <div class='input-group date' id='datetimepicker2'>
                    <input type='text' name="pickdate"  class="form-control" />
                      <span class="input-group-addon">
                        <span class="glyphicon glyphicon-calendar"></span>
                      </span>
                  </div>
                </div>
                <div class="col-sm-2 text-right padding5"><label>Time slot</label></div>
                  <div class='col-sm-4'>
                    <select name="order_time_slot" class="form-control">
                      <?php foreach ($timeslots as $time_slot) { ?>
                        <option value="<?php echo $time_slot['key']; ?>"><?php echo $time_slot['value']; ?></option>
                      <?php } ?>
                    </select>
                  </div>
               </div>
```

Answer (score 0):

You can Use VQmod to modify core file without changing core file.VQmod search the file then it will replace or add  your file

Comment: To install VQmod mode :https://github.com/vqmod/vqmod/wiki/Installing-vQmod-on-OpenCart

Comment: i am edited core file using Vqmod, but after disabling the module that edited code still reflecting